# Кодировка при занесении данных

Tags: mysql, android, activity

Здравствуйте, нужна помощь. Осуществляю занесение данных из android клиента в mysql базу данных на сервере через php скрипты, которые находятся на сервере. Но при занесении данных на русском языке в бд заносятся ??????, а если отправляю латиницу все работает нормально. 
В структуре таблицы, в которую отправляю данные поле указал с кодировкой cp1251_bin(для русских символов), но не работает.
Php скрипт, который заносит данные в бд.

```
    <?php
        $data = file_get_contents('php://input');
        $json = json_decode($data);
        $change = $json->{'changing'};
        $mysqli = new mysqli("**********", "******",       "******", "******");
        /* проверка соединения */
        if (mysqli_connect_errno()) {
            printf("Соединение не установлено: %s\n",        mysqli_connect_error());
        exit();
        }
        $query = "INSERT INTO Changes (Changing) VALUES ('$change')";
        $mysqli->query($query);
        printf ("ID новой записи: %d.\n", $mysqli->insert_id);
    ?>
```

[image: Структура таблицы Changes]

**Структура таблицы Changes**
Запрос из android клиента в php скрипту.

```
    public class Sender extends AsyncTask<String, String, String> {
    public int value;

    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(String... params) {
        if (dateReceptionEditText.getText().toString().equals("")){
            value = 1;
        }
        else {
            int doctorPosition = doctorSpinner.getSelectedItemPosition() - 1;
            int registrationPosition = registrationSpinner.getSelectedItemPosition() - 1;
            String dateReception = dateReceptionEditText.getText().toString();

            client = new DefaultHttpClient();
            post = new HttpPost("***********/InsertTicketScript.php");
            HttpConnectionParams.setConnectionTimeout(client.getParams(), 10000); // Timeout
            HttpResponse response;
            JSONObject json = new JSONObject();

            try {
                json.put("doctorKod", arrayIdDoctor[doctorPosition]);
                json.put("registrationKod", arrayIdRegistration[registrationPosition]);
                json.put("dateReception", dateReception);
                post.setHeader("json", json.toString());
                StringEntity se = new StringEntity(json.toString());
                se.setContentEncoding(new BasicHeader(HTTP.CONTENT_TYPE, "application/json"));
                post.setEntity(se);
                response = client.execute(post);

                if (response != null) {
                    InputStream in = response.getEntity().getContent(); // Get the
                    Log.i("Read from Server", in.toString());
                }

                value = 0;
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }

        return String.valueOf(value);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String s) {
        super.onPostExecute(s);
        if (s.equals("0")) {
            Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), R.string.Send, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
        else{
            Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), R.string.AddContent, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    }
}
```

Пожалуйста помогите!

Comment: android работает с кодировкой utf-8, рекомендуется все перевести в эту кодировку. Сам проект и все его файлы и текстовые ресурсы.

Comment: А поля таблицы тоже в utf8?

Comment: @Contact, да, тоже в *utf8*, естественно. т.е., не надо никаких переопределений *charset*-ов для таблиц или полей. делайте дефолтным *charset*-ом для **базы данных**  *utf8*. и всё.

Answer (score 1):

Первым запросом вызывайте `SET NAMES`. Подробности [тут](http://dev.ezoterik.info/mysql-i-russkaya-kodirovka/) ну и [тут](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/charset-connection.html) (по-английски)

Comment: я добавид  $mysqli->query("SET NAMES 'cp1251'");
 $mysqli->query("SET CHARACTER SET 'cp1251'"); но все равно вопр. знаки остались

Comment: Значит в описании таблицы или полей указана другая кодировка. Причем после замены данные не восстановятся. Покажите вывод запроса `SHOW CREATE TABLE`.

Comment: CREATE TABLE `Changes` (
 `IdChange` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
 `Changing` varchar(30) CHARACTER SET cp1251 COLLATE cp1251_bin NOT NULL,
 PRIMARY KEY (`IdChange`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM AUTO_INCREMENT=42 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_unicode_ci

Comment: Вопросительные знаки на тех данных, которые вы добавляли до того как выволняли запрос `SET NAMES`? Если да, то можете про них забыть и перезаписывать заново.

Comment: Вообще я вначале вызвал SET NAMES, а потом уже выполнял insert запрос

Comment: Так вы получаете данные от Android клиента без перекодировки. Java работает с кодировкой UTF-16. Соответственно в этой кодировке данные попадают в PHP, и оттуда в базу. Значит вам нужно задавать `SET NAMES 'ucs2';` или перекодировать данные (не важно на какой стороне).